# laravel factory persisting id's across multiple models

Tags: laravel, factory, laravel-5.7

Having one hell of a time figuring out how to persist certain data across multiple model factories. For example:

Lets say i have 4 tables(edit): user, a, b, c

The relationships in these 3 tables are as follows:

- ALL have a user_id
- a_id is in both tables b & c
- b_id is in table c

I am going around in circles trying to persist this data correctly. Any thoughts?

Comment: And regarding the laravel docs they give examples for a relationship one layer deep. Not understanding how I am supposed to persist that data across all layers though!

Comment: you have 4 databases or 4 tables?

Comment: sorry tables within one database

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
What I have had to do is in each factory is just call the parent database that I had just created and pull random ID's not ideal at this point - but will do the job for now ... if anyone has any other ideas let me know.

Cheers

Comment: if you are using something like `'a' => factory(\App\A::class)->create()->id`, I believe wrapping it in a function could help you. But if you could paste more code in it, I believe it would be easier to understand the problem

Comment: yes that helps for one of the models... but not all...  for example i need the same user_id across all tables.